# show sum per time period and sum per entire time span

Tags: mysql

I have a product that sells monthly and I have the user's email

I want to see the total sum purchased per month per email.

Also the total amount purchased per email for all months combined

Comment: show your table structure and what you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Like This :

I understand question like this

```
     select  email,sum(amount),'2' as ord from ( 
     select email,sum(amount) as amount ,month(d1) from t1 group by 
     month(d1),email) as t group by email

      union all 

      select email,sum(amount) as amount,
     '1' as ord from t1 group by month(d1),email

     order by ord
```

This query return first show sum of amount per month and email after that show sum of amount per email